# How to create controls from code in a custom control?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

In MainPage.xaml.cs (Silverlight Application) I can do something like this:

```
StackPanel myStackPanel = new StackPanel();

Button myButton = new Button();
myButton.Content = "Button";
myButton.Width = 200;
myButton.Height = 30;

Button myButton1 = new Button();
myButton1.Content = "Button 1";
myButton1.Width = 200;
myButton1.Height = 30;

myStackPanel.Children.Add(myButton);
myStackPanel.Children.Add(myButton1);

this.LayoutRoot.Children.Add(myStackPanel);
```

What is the equivalent of this code in a custom control when I'm trying to create these controls from the code?

**Update:**

My question is probably too confusing. I'l try better formulation.
So, I have

**Generic.xaml**

```
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DemoAddControlLib">

    <Style TargetType="local:DemoControlShowtime">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="local:DemoControlShowtime">
                    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRootControl">
                        <Button x:Name="Button1" Content="Hi" Width="150" Height="30"></Button>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

And code:

**DemoControlShowtime.cs**

```
[TemplatePart(Name = "Button1", Type=typeof(Button))]
public class DemoControlShowtime : Control
{
    public DemoControlShowtime()
    {
        this.DefaultStyleKey = typeof(DemoControlShowtime);
    }

    // Events
    public override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        Button1 = (Button)GetTemplateChild("Button1");
    }

    private Button button1;

    private Button Button1
    {
        get { return button1; }
        set
        {
            if (button1 != null)
            {
                Button1.Click -= new RoutedEventHandler(myButton_Click);
            }

            button1 = value;

            button1.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(myButton_Click);
        }
    }

    void myButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Button1.Content = "Hello Button";


    }
}
```

If I click on Button1 the Content changes from "Hi" to "Hello Button". I want, when Button1 is clicked, to add StackPanel with two buttons as its Children into the Grid LayoutRootControl.
I know there is Visibility property and put it into the xaml would be easier but I'm curious how to do it from the code.

I hope this is much clearer than the question was before.

Comment: Could you clarify your question? I don't understand exaclty what you're looking for. Are you wondering how to add a CustomControl to your myStackPanel?  Or are you wondering how to make myStackPanel be a custom control that you add to the LayoutRoot?

Comment: I'm interested how to add programmatically StackPanel with its Children to my Custom Control (Silverlight Library) - i.e. MyDemoControl.cs (here should be the code with myStackPanel) + Generic.xaml. Maybe I'm accessing the problem in a totally wrong way.

Comment: So you would like to do something like this: MyDemoControl has a button and a MyCustomControl, where MyCustomControl has something in it (like a StackPanel)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code isn't really any different to what you have.  The only variation is that the field `LayoutRoot` is not created for you.

However with this line of code:-

```
 Grid LayoutRoot = GetTemplateChild("LayoutRootControl") as Grid;
```

The rest of your code would be identical (although you should test whether LayoutRoot is null first).

Answer (score 0):

It appears to me that your are just wondering how to use a custom control in multiple places.

I've created a custom control (MyCustomControl) that has the StackPanel shown in your code, then used it multiple times on the MainPage.

**MyCustomControl.xaml**

```
<UserControl x:Class="SilverlightApplication2.MyCustomControl"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d">

<StackPanel>
    <Button Content="Button 1" Height="30" Width="200"/>
    <Button Content="Button 2" Height="30" Width="200"/>
</StackPanel>
```

**MyCustomControl.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class MyCustomControl : UserControl
{
    public MyCustomControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Then I've used that custom control twice in the main view.

**MainPage.xaml**

```
<UserControl x:Class="SilverlightApplication2.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SilverlightApplication2"
d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="400">

<StackPanel>
    <local:MyCustomControl Margin="10" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
    <local:MyCustomControl Margin="10" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
</StackPanel>
```

**MainPage.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class MainPage : UserControl
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: Thank you @JSprang for your effort and time but I had to update my question. It was really confusing.